# Run Flutter integration test groups with Firebase test lab

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I have several test groups written in my flutter app. I can run all the tests in the firebase test lab without an issue. Now I want to run a specific test group with the firebase. the command I use to upload apk is this

```
command = "gcloud firebase test android run \
        --type=instrumentation \
        --app=#{debug_apk_path} \
        --test=#{test_apk_path} \
        --device=model=tangorpro,version=33,locale=en_US,orientation=landscape \
        --timeout=30m \
        --async \
        --format=json"
```

I have only one test entry file. is there a way to do this with Firebase test lab?
we can run separate test groups using the below flutter command

```
flutter test --name "Test Group" integration_test/app_test.dart
```

I want to do the same on Firebase Test Lab.

I tried creating separate test entry files for each group like below. but it also didn't work.

```
integration_test/test1.dart
integration_test/test2.dart
integration_test/test3.dart
integration_test/all_tests.dart
```

.....................

```
import 'test1.dart' as test1;
import 'test2.dart' as test2;

void main() {
  test1.main();
  test2.main();
  ...
}
```